# Alternative options to MS SQL REPLICATION

Tags: windows-mobile, replication, windows-ce

I would like to ask if there are any alternative options to ms sql replication(this is what i am using now) for replicating data.

Creating a custom architecture for replicating is a good idea?

PS. The alternative option must support mobile databases that run on Windows CE/Mobile

EDIT: The application should be able to work offline for a while, then on demand by the user to synchronize with the server database by sending/receiving all new/updated data to and from the server.

Comment: If you say why you need an alternative (what limitation of inbuilt replication is a problem), maybe easier to answer.

Comment: my major pain is deployment and all the problems that this brings when it comes to replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, based on your requirements.

1) Log shipping, where the log from your central DB is copied to other servers at a regular interval, and that log is applied to the DB. This approach only works if you have a central publishing DB, and a number of subscribing databases

2) Use SSIS or DTS to regularly copy data between databases, this can be bi-directional aslong as your keys are unique, use GUIDs or ID ranges

3) Detach central DB, copy the underlying files (data and log) to destination servers. This has the disadvantage of taking the central DB offline, albeit briefly.

I think creating a custom architecture for replication is a really bad idea, but without knowing what your requirements are it's hard to suggest a complete solution.